# Perl select returning undef on sysread when using Windows, IPC::Open3, and IO::Socket->socketpair()

Tags: windows, perl, ipcopen3, socketpair

I found [this example](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=811650) (posted by @ikegami) of a way to use IPC::Open3 on windows using sockets.  The problem is that, when I run it, I get an error *An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host* on the `sysread`.  The command runs, the `select` works correctly, but the `sysread` is getting an `undef` instead of the expected `0` for end of file.  This behavior is not the same for all commands.  If I change the command to `echo Hello World!` it does not cause the error.  Any idea what is going on here?

Here is the code from the example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Select qw( );
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );
use Socket     qw( AF_UNIX SOCK_STREAM PF_UNSPEC );

print( "REMOVE ME: getting started\n" );

sub _pipe {
    socketpair($_[0], $_[1], AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC)
        or return undef;
    shutdown($_[0], 1);  # No more writing for reader
    shutdown($_[1], 0);  # No more reading for writer
    return 1;
}

sub _open3 {
    local (*TO_CHLD_R,     *TO_CHLD_W);
    local (*FR_CHLD_R,     *FR_CHLD_W);
    local (*FR_CHLD_ERR_R, *FR_CHLD_ERR_W);

    if ($^O =~ /Win32/) {
        _pipe(*TO_CHLD_R,     *TO_CHLD_W    ) or die $^E;
        _pipe(*FR_CHLD_R,     *FR_CHLD_W    ) or die $^E;
        _pipe(*FR_CHLD_ERR_R, *FR_CHLD_ERR_W) or die $^E;
    } else {
        pipe(*TO_CHLD_R,     *TO_CHLD_W    ) or die $!;
        pipe(*FR_CHLD_R,     *FR_CHLD_W    ) or die $!;
        pipe(*FR_CHLD_ERR_R, *FR_CHLD_ERR_W) or die $!;
    }

    my $pid = open3('>&TO_CHLD_R', '<&FR_CHLD_W', '<&FR_CHLD_ERR_W', @_);

    return ( $pid, *TO_CHLD_W, *FR_CHLD_R, *FR_CHLD_ERR_R );
}

# when i change the command to 'echo Hello World' it works...
my ($pid, $to_chld, $fr_chld, $fr_chld_err) =
    _open3('cmd /c "dir /s/b"');

my %objs;

my $in_sel  = IO::Select->new();
my $out_sel = IO::Select->new();

for my $fh ($fr_chld, $fr_chld_err) {
    my $obj = {
        buf => '',
    };
    $objs{ fileno($fh) } = $obj;
    $in_sel->add($fh);
}

close($to_chld);

while ($in_sel->count() + $out_sel->count()) {
    my ($ins, $outs) = IO::Select::select($in_sel, $out_sel, undef);

    for my $fh (@$ins) {
        my $obj = $objs{ fileno($fh) };
        our $buf; local *buf = \( $obj->{buf} );
        my $bytes_read = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
        if (!$bytes_read) {
            warn("Error reading from child: $!\n")
                if !defined($bytes_read);
            $in_sel->remove($fh);
        }
    }

    for my $fh (@$outs) {
    }
}

waitpid($pid, 0);

print("STDOUT:\n$objs{ fileno( $fr_chld     ) }{buf}");
print("\n" );
print("STDERR:\n$objs{ fileno( $fr_chld_err ) }{buf}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because something like `shutdown` was used instead of something like `close`. Sounds safe to ignore.

`grep $!{$_}, keys %!` shows `ECONNRESET`, so just change

```
warn("Error reading from child: $!\n")
    if !defined($bytes_read);
```

to

```
warn("Error reading from child: $!\n")
    if !defined($bytes_read) && !$!{ECONNRESET};
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure i fully understand why it would be happening though (especially since it appears to only be some commands).  But this worked.  Out of curiosity, I cant help but notice that you are the same ikegami that posted the original code on perlmonks in 2009...  Is that site still a good place for perl questions, or do the monks now spend more time on the SO?

Comment: Don't know exactly why either, beyond "different programs are free to do different things". Both are great places.

Comment: In case you care, I leveraged the knowledge from this to put together a library for running IPC::Open3 that works on windows and unix.  You can take a look here if you are curious: https://github.com/lucastheisen/ipc-open3-callback.  I'd like to add it to CPAN but they guy who owns `IPC::Open3` has not responded to my request to expand on his namespace...

Comment: That's pretty cool, though keep in mind it can already be done with awesome modules IPC::Run3 and IPC::Run. IPC::Open3 is a core module "owned" by the Perl5 Porters (the developers of Perl itself), so contact `perl5-porters@perl.org`.

Comment: I have seen `IPC::Run`, and `IPC::Run3`.  I wanted to use them (_true CPAN believer here_), but couldn't make it fit my use case.  Basically we have an automation library that runs commands on remote systems.  Things like `ssh automation@devserver tail -f some.log`.  With IPC::Run, i can store the output in a var or send it to a handle, but i need to perform an action each time data becomes available (print locally).  Of course i could get handles and use select, but that is basically what this library does.  Do you think that provides enough utility to be its own module?

Comment: With IPC::Run and IPC::Run3, you can do EXACTLY what your module does. To replicate the example in your Synopsis with IPC::Run: `run(['sh', '-c', 'Hello World'], '>', sub { print( "$_[0]\n" ); }, '2>', sub { print( STDERR "$_[0]\n" ); });`

Comment: DANG.  It says it right in the doc, i just missed it.  Was looking for `sub {}` but it says `\&sub`.  You are right and i greatly appreciate all of your comments and help.  It has been a great learning experience.  Monk you are!

Comment: IPC::Run appears not to be capable of `sub` for `out` or `err` on windows: `croak "Can't spawn a subroutine on Win32" if Win32_MODE && ref eq "CODE";`...